# TextMate/TextWrangler Document Reverts

Tags: macos, textmate, bbedit

This happens to me when I'm editing a document (usually a Javascript script) in TextMate (1 and 2) and TextWrangler.

I have this document open in another app, and in certain occasions, the document within TextMate/TextWrangler would revert itself to the previously saved versions whenever I hit Cmd+S. This is very annoying as my changes are basically gone.

I'm pretty sure both TextMate and TextWrangler are not sandboxed. The version of TextWrangler I have is the one from the Mac App Store.

Anyone has any workarounds for this?

Answer (score 1):

For TextWrangler there is a setting in the preferences — it's the second from the top in the following screenshot.

[image: TextWrangler settings.]

There is probably a setting in TextMate too, but as of version 2, it's probably a `defaults` setting, since almost everything has ben stripped from the preferences GUI.